# Salesforce Lightning Experience: main menu responsiveness

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, mobile

I'm working on a project where all lightning apps + components need to be built  fully responsive. I am using Chrome/Safari dev tools + seeing some strange things happen with the main menu. This is the menu set by the tabs in the Setup. It never collapses to a hamburger/mobile friendly option. And as a developer, it seems you have no control over it.

It appears this menu is only responsive down to a 480px device width? Is this correct? I am having trouble finding any sort of documentation around this.

How do you plan for when the user will use the Salesforce1 app vs logging in to Salesforce via the browser? And how do you keep the UI consistent?

Answer (score 0):

The $Browser global value provider returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

For more details and examples, please check the link below:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm